# Finding a primary decomposition of an ideal in $\Bbb Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

> I wanted to get an idea on how to find a primary decomposition of an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

I've read a lot of posts, and most of strategies are quite specific for polynomial rings like $K[x,y]$ and the ideals in question are usually generated by monomials. So I was wondering if the strategy involved also works in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$? If not, what are some common techniques that I can try? Say for example

> $$I = \langle x^3-2x, x^4-4\rangle$$

Any other examples to illustrate the techniques is also  appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: $(x^3-2x, x^4-4)=(x^2-2)\cap(4,x)$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455885/intersection-of-two-primary-ideals-in-mathbbzx